# How can I find the string "Moved to Quarantine" via Splunk using Regex?

Tags: regex, splunk

How can I find the string "Moved to Quarantine" via Splunk using Regex? (If anything, what would the Regex line be?)

Script would be essentially  "anything Moved to Quarantine anything"

This is the line I'm working with;

> Message=Computer-0104 [Tuesday, March 13, 2018 3:31:39 AM (GMT-06:00)]
> (Virus Scan SP1): Result: Moved to Quarantine:
> not-a-virus:HEUR:AdWare.Script.Generic

What i'm working on;
`.+?(?=Result:\sMoved to Quarantine:)|:\tMoved\sto\sQuarantine:\s`

[Example Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCrEl.png)

Comment: Script is the wrong word. It would be a Regex line or Splunk + Regex line.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for a string in Splunk is a matter of simply entering the string.

```
index=foo "Moved to Quarantine"
```

will return all events containing "Moved to Quarantine".

Regex strings can be just as simple.

```
index=foo | regex _raw="Moved to Quarantine"
```